# slow query retrieving most recent record

Tags: mysql

I am having difficulties retrieving the most current record from a history table.  I am just working on one part of the retrieve for the moment.  The final will be a join of the most recent history entry with the clients table.

The clients table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Clients
 (
        id                      int(8) auto_increment not null primary key, 
        LastName                varchar(50), 
        First                  varchar(50),
        CanContact             TINYINT(1)
);
```

Client History (~300,000 records):

```
CREATE TABLE ClientHistory
(
        id                      int(8) auto_increment not null primary key, 
        Client                  int(8),
        Act_Date                datetime,
        Activity                int(8)
);
create index idx_ClientHistory_Client on ClientHistory(Client);
create index idx_ClientHistory_Act_Date on ClientHistory(Act_Date);
```

**Question 1:**
`SELECT id, MAX(Act_Date), Notes from ClientHistory group by Client`.  This retrieves the most current Date, but the id and Notes are actually from the oldest record.

```
mysql> select id, Client, Act_Date, Activity from ClientHistory where client=18176;
+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+
| id     | Client | Act_Date            | Activity |
+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+
| 346725 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 09:29:35 |        4 |
| 346726 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 09:29:39 |        3 |
| 346727 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 09:44:29 |        4 |
| 346728 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 09:44:36 |        3 |
| 346737 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 10:35:10 |        4 |
| 346739 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 10:49:43 |        4 |
| 346740 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 10:54:57 |       29 |
| 346787 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:37:15 |       23 |
| 346788 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:37:20 |       23 |
| 346789 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:37:23 |       23 |
| 346790 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:37:27 |       23 |
| 346791 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:37:30 |       23 |
| 346792 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:37:34 |       20 |
| 346793 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:37:51 |       13 |
| 346798 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 15:50:51 |       25 |
| 346808 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 16:10:55 |       13 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, Client, Act_Date, MAX(Act_Date), Activity from ClientHistory where client=18176;
+--------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| id     | Client | Act_Date            | MAX(Act_Date)       | Activity |
+--------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 346725 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 09:29:35 | 2015-09-04 16:10:55 |        4 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select id, Client, Act_Date, Activity from ClientHistory where client=18176 group by Client order by Act_Date desc;
+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+
| id     | Client | Act_Date            | Activity |
+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+
| 346725 |  18176 | 2015-09-04 09:29:35 |        4 |
+--------+--------+---------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Question 2** the below query is insanely slow (~ 6 seconds):

```
select * from Clients
LEFT JOIN ( 
    select c1.* from ClientHistory as c1
        LEFT JOIN ClientHistory as c2 on c1.client = c2.client and c1.Act_Date < c2.Act_Date where c2.Client is null
        ) as ctemp on Clients.id = ctemp.Client
        where CanContact=true order by LastName, First;
```

The culprit is:

```
select c1.* from ClientHistory as c1
        LEFT JOIN ClientHistory as c2 on c1.client = c2.client and c1.Act_Date < c2.Act_Date where c2.Client is null;
And the explain:
explain select c1.* from ClientHistory as c1 LEFT JOIN ClientHistory as c2 on c1.client = c2.client and c1.Act_Date < c2.Act_Date where c2.Client is null;
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                       | key                      | key_len | ref       | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c1    | ALL  | NULL                                                | NULL                     | NULL    | NULL      | 330120 | NULL        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c2    | ref  | idx_ClientHistory_Client,idx_ClientHistory_Act_Date | idx_ClientHistory_Client | 5       | c1.Client |      8 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-----------+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am quite baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 1:

```
SELECT id, MAX(Act_Date), Notes from ClientHistory group by Client
```

Is not ANSI compliant. You have to list all your columns which do not have a function applied to it in you `GROUP BY` clause

In this case it might be possible that that returns more then 1 record since MAX(Act_Date) might be multiple for a single client. If that is not the case for your data, you can use:

```
SELECT Client,MAX(id), MAX(Act_Date) from ClientHistory group by Client
```

Notes is a more difficult field to retrieve, but now you have the `id` you can retrieve that by joining the table back on itself by id.

Comment: FYI, with your direction, this is the current query that returns in .45 seconds select * from Clients left join (
 SELECT t.*, Notes, Activity, Act_Date from ClientHistory
  INNER JOIN ( select MAX(Act_date), MAX(id) as mid, Client from ClientHistory group by Client) as t on t.mid = ClientHistory.id) as ch on Client=Clients.id
    ;

Answer (score 0):

You can do a where in and a join

```
SELECT  * from ClientHistory 
where (Act_Date, client) in ( select MAX(Act_Date), client)
   from ClientHistory group by Client) 
inner join client on client.id = ClientHistory .client;
```

Comment: this query, without the inner join, never completed.  It timed out after 600 seconds.

Comment: There was an error  .. i have update the answer .. let me know wrong pair act_date, client .. inside the in  clause...then don't match

Comment: ok, that's much better.   both your answer and the one from Norbert seem to work

Comment: well .. so both they are at least useful..  .. my give you all the column you need .. the others falis  .. if you add others column ..